# How to find the last element of ng-repeater when testing with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor

I need to find and click the last element (byID) of ng-repeater.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`last()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.last):

```
var elm = element.all(by.repeater('item in items')).last();
elm.click();
```